# Excel changing number to date when using find and replace on the entire column

Tags: excel

I have a csv file with ~ 15k lines and there are a couple of columns where I need to replace comma with a period. The first thing I did was set my column number format to "text". After that I wanted to search and replace all the commas, however, it was still changing the numbers into dates. When I manually changed a comma everything worked as expected.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there an excel solution for this, or do I have to use alternative means?

Edit:

It's a file that needs to be imported using an import script. The columns I need to replace are prices. The import script recognizes periods as cent separators (instead of commas). The cells that have at least one side of the number smaller than 12 are converted into months. Changing the import script would require too much work for it to be feasible at the moment.

Comment: Please provide more info - give an example of what your cell originally contained, why you needed to replace the commas with periods, etc.

Comment: In order to do this within Excel (or VBA), you must set the column format to "text" (or prefix the entry with a single quote `'`) **BEFORE** you import the data to that column. Without knowing more about your import process, original data, and how it appears after you import it, it is not possible to advise further.  But it does seem as if some modification in your import process will be necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with CSV files in Excel can be a bit problematic. The issue is Excel tries to guess the data type (date, number or text) of each cell and then make changes.
A better tool for for text files is Powershell, here is an example that could be modified for your task:

```
Import-Csv YourInputFile.csv | % {
  $_.your_first_field = $_.your_first_field -replace ',', '.' 
  $_.your_second_field = $_.your_second_field -replace ',', '.' 
  $_
} | Export-Csv YourOutputFile.csv
```

Nice thing about Powershell is that you could add couple more lines of code to scale it so that it could handle multiple files